# Download Manager Request setNotificationVisiblity

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-download-manager

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request

> [**`setNotificationVisibility(int visiblity)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request#setNotificationVisibility(int))
>
> Control whether a system notification is posted by the download manager while this download is running or when it is completed. If enabled, the download manager posts notifications about downloads through the system `NotificationManager`. By default, a notification is shown only when the download is in progress.
>
> It can take the following values: `VISIBILITY_HIDDEN`, `VISIBILITY_VISIBLE`, `VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED`.
>
> If set to `VISIBILITY_HIDDEN`, this requires the permission `android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION`.

So I want to `setNotificationVisiblity` to `VISIBLITY_HIDDEN`. According to [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request#setNotificationVisibility(int)) I need to set the permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Where is the permission?

I can't find permission `android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION` in [**`Manifest.permission`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission)

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission

Has this permission been removed from Android? If I set `downaloadReq.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN)` without permission it throws a `SecurityException`. So what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your permission is indeed missing in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Just add the following line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION"/>
```